# Selenium with ASP.Net?

Tags: selenium

My company for which i am an employee uses ASP.Net Technology; if the User interface is DotNet component instead of HTML COMPONENT, Can i use selenium tool?

Answer (score 4):

Selenium is a browser automation tool. This means that your application has to be run in a browser for Selenium to automate it. You say that your user interface is a .NET component using ASP.NET. If you mean that your application is a web application built using ASP.NET which renders HTML to a user's browser, then yes, you can use Selenium to test it. If your application is a Windows Forms, Silverlight, or Windows Presentation Framework (WPF) application, then no, you can't use Selenium directly to automate navigation of your application.